# How do I read a non-xml file from an Ant task?

Tags: ant

The [XmlProperty](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) task is perfect to read an xml well-formed file in Ant.

But how to read a non-XML one?

More precisely, How To Read a pattern from a non-XML file?

Answer (score 13):

Check out the [LoadFile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) task.  It allows you to load a file into an Ant property that you can then access from other tasks.  The LoadFile tasks also supports filters/filter chains, so you can do things like read the first 5 lines of the file into the property or read lines that only contain certain words, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can read a [.properties file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) using the `file` option of the [`property` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).